# JSP/Servlet validation - forward vs redirect

Tags: java, validation, servlets, redirect, forward

I'd like to accomplish the following:

I have a form represented in a JSP – let's call this `input.jsp`. This form submits to a servlet which will create objects in a DB – lets call this `CreateServlet`. When the form is successfully submitted, the servlet should direct the user back to `input.jsp` and display a success message. When validation fails, it should redirect back to `input.jsp`, display an error message, retain the input values.

I can think of a few options:

1. On validation failure I can use a `RequestDispatcher` to perform a forward to `input.jsp`. This would allow me to easily display the validation errors and input parameters from the form. However, I know that [a forward should not be used in the case of performing an edit operation](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=181), so when the request is successful I should not do a forward and should do a redirect instead. The problem with a redirect is that I can't set attributes as easily unless I pass it in the URL, e.g. `input.jsp?success=true`.
2. I can store validation messages, success messages, and input values in the session, and always perform a redirect. After the JSP has displayed the page then it can remove these attributes from the session.

I am using plain servlets and JSP and not any framework like Struts. What is the recommended practice in this case?

Comment: I had the same problem in a Web application (using an MVC framework) and used second approach (that the MVC framework eases by providing access to the `HttpSession` but in the end is like calling `HttpServletRequest#getSession`). Worked with no problems even if user opens the same page in different tabs within the same browser.

Comment: use page level cookie instead of session to store messages

Answer (score 0):

i will choose second option if i were you. My reason :

- Make it an object to encapsulate all input in that form. it will
     easier to maintain if i need to add attribute to the form.
- It more secure because your url will clean from attributes.

It will very easy if you used framework like struts. Everything will be handled by them.